# FullCalendar 2.2.6 timezone ignored

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar (http://fullcalendar.io/) and everything works great except the timezone. For some reason I can't get the time to change like it does in the example on the website, and I can't see what's different in my code than the example here:

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.6/demos/timezones.html

The code on my project is much more complicated so I tried to duplicate the example as closely as possible but it still isn't working:

```
<body>
    <h1>Calendar:</h1>
    <div class="calendar"></div>
</body>

<script>
    function renderCalendar() {
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-11-12',
            timezone: 'Europe\/London',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [{"title":"All Day Event","start":"2014-11-01"},{"title":"Long Event","start":"2014-11-07","end":"2014-11-10"},{"id":"999","title":"Repeating Event","start":"2014-11-09T16:00:00-05:00"},{"id":"999","title":"Repeating Event","start":"2014-11-16T16:00:00-05:00"},{"title":"Conference","start":"2014-11-11","end":"2014-11-13"},{"title":"Meeting","start":"2014-11-12T10:30:00","end":"2014-11-12T12:30:00"},{"title":"Lunch","start":"2014-11-12T12:00:00-05:00"},{"title":"Meeting","start":"2014-11-12T14:30:00-05:00"},{"title":"Happy Hour","start":"2014-11-12T17:30:00-05:00"},{"title":"Dinner","start":"2014-11-12T20:00:00+00:00"},{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2014-11-13T07:00:00-05:00"},{"url":"http:\/\/google.com\/","title":"Click for Google","start":"2014-11-28"}],
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            },
            eventRender: function(event, el) {
                // render the timezone offset below the event title
                if (event.start.hasZone()) {
                    el.find('.fc-title').after(
                    $('<div class="tzo"/>').text(event.start.format('Z'))
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }
    renderCalendar();
</script>
```

The events listed are the exact events pulled from the example on the FullCalendar.io website. The calendar renders fine, but changing the timezone parameter doesn't change the time displayed for the event:

Setting timezone as "none" shows +00:00 below the event

Setting timezone as "local" shows -05:00 below the event (EST, my time zone)

Setting timezone as a specific location (ex, "America/Chicago") shows +00:00 below the event regardless of what location is specified

In none of these instances is the time for the event displayed on the calendar changed; if the time entered is 14:00:00 it's displayed as 2p regardless of timezone settings. There is probably something obvious I'm missing somewhere but I just can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

(Note that this is FullCalendar v2 so the ignoreTimezone parameter doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to render your events with timezone
[events function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/)

then set your timezone in options.